# 'Вот оно что' versus 'вон оно что'

Tags: значения

Very simply, what is the difference between the phrases 'вот оно что' or 'вон оно что?'

Comment: Very simply, no difference

Comment: It means the same thing.......

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No real difference. You may think it like *This is it* vs *That's it*.

"*Вот*" is a "pointer"-word for any object near to the speaker. "*Вон*" is its counterpart for any distant object. (BTW. There are several other meanings insignificant for this topic, e.g. *Вон!* = *Get out!*).

That is *Вот* is a *Here*-pointer as in *Here you are*, and *Вон* is a *There*-pointer as in *There you are* (but note that *here*-location as in "You are here" would become *здесь* in Russian, and "You are there" will be *там*).

Yet in this particular case the whole expression is rather another way of saying: "Oh, I see". So both "Вот оно что" and "Вон оно что" have absolutely same meaning.

Still there's one more point to note. The dictionaries mark the word "*Вон*" as "colloquial". My guess, this is due to the "point-with-a-finger" effect: saying "вон" often implies pointing with a finger, which is improper.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Artemix: You are wrong. This answer clearly shows all the tiny difference between these two phrases and states that this difference is insignificant. I could only suggest to make the answer more elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

Both are colloquial expressions of understanding something told by someone else. While "вот оно что" из emotionally neutral, "вон оно что" carries a bit of surprise or even sympathy for the other party in the conversation. The latter version is unlikely to be used in formal speech.

**P.S.** Examples of formal and personal usage, where proper choice is preferable.

(business negotiations)

```
- Извините за задержку с платежом, забастовка банковских служащих продлится ещё два дня.

- Вот оно что. Теперь понятно, давайте обсудим ситуацию.
```

(informal situation)

```
- Жена не смогла поехать (к вам в гости) вместе со мной, она приболела.

- Вон оно что... Ну передавайте ей привет, пусть поправляется.
```